# What is this pop up by Samsungs clock?

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, floating, identification

pardon my lack of knowledge. Can anyone tell me what this popup from Samsungs clock is when an alarm goes off? Is it a fragment, or an activity of its own? I was reading and android.com says that starting activities when the user is on screen is restricted. It can't be done because it is obtrusive. Could you please tell me what this pop up is called, and is it an activity, fragment, something else?[image: popup]

Comment: Did you read the [time sensitive notifications guide](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive), which explains how to display these types of heads up notifications?

Comment: I did, but that notification shoes up over the screen instead of the notification section, do you know how I would do this?